# Doubly linked list.Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have a task to delete blocks of odd numbers.
For example:
0-4-5-7-9-10 to 0-4-10.
To imlpement this I wrote this function:

```
void delete_odd_el(Tsnum *&Start)
{
    Tsnum *wp, *pp, *del_el;
    wp = Start;
    while(wp != nullptr)
    {
      if(wp->num % 2 == 1)
      {

        while(wp!=nullptr)
        {
          if(wp->num % 2 == 0) break;
          del_el = wp;
          wp = wp->next;
          wp->prev = del_el->prev;
          delete del_el;
        }
      }
      wp = wp->next;
    }
}
```

But when I run it I get segmentation fault. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This approach seems pretty weird. What would the difference be between what you are trying to do and just handling odd numbered nodes one at a time as you see them?

Comment: To make sure this is a verifiable example you shouldn't be using non standard types like Tsnum.

Comment: Agreed with Ryan, the inner loop looks...odd.

Comment: The problem seems to me that you need to do `wp->prev->next = wp` right before the `delete del_el` otherwise the next pointer is never updated.

Comment: The task to delete block of odd numbers if it single skip

Comment: @AlexFr this doesn't do that. What is considered a "single step"?

Comment: For starters, post a [MCVE].  (You should be using `std::list`, BTW.)

Comment: How is the problem different from removing every odd number from the list?

Comment: @Daniel H I wrote before I need to remove groups of odd numbers not all odd numbers. If I have next list : 1 2 4 6 7 9 11 16 I should delete this group (7 9 11) and get next list  1 2 4  6 16

Comment: Why do you have a doubly nested `while`  loop?  All you need is one loop.

Comment: @AlexFr So groups of size 1 don’t count?

Comment: @Daniel H yes  I need to skip it.

Comment: Previous node next pointer not updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys if this help you:

```
   void delete_odd_el(Tsnum *&Start)
    {
        Tsnum *wp;
        wp = Start;
        while(wp!= nullptr)
        {
            if(wp->num % 2 ==1 && wp->next !=nullptr && wp->next->num % 2 == 1)
            {
                while(wp != nullptr && wp->num % 2 == 1)
                {
                    if(wp->prev !=nullptr)
                    {
                        wp = wp->prev;
                        if(wp->next->next != nullptr)
                        {
                            wp->next = wp->next->next;
                            delete wp->next->prev;
                            wp->next->prev = wp;
                        }
                        else

                        {
                            delete wp->next;
                            wp->next = nullptr;
                        }
                        wp = wp->next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(wp->next != nullptr)
                        {
                            wp = wp->next;
                            delete wp->prev;
                            wp->prev = nullptr;
                            Start = wp;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            delete wp;
                            wp = nullptr;
                            Start = wp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                wp = wp->next;
        } 
    }
```